# Eigenvalues of a differential operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue

I am interested to know if there are any general techniques for diagonalizing the operator of the form
$$\left({\rm i}\partial_t- \frac{1}{2}t^{3/2}\mathbf{A}\partial_p+ t^{-3/2}p\mathbf{B} \right)$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is an $n\times n$ diagonal matrix of constants, and $\mathbf{B}$ is an antisymmetric matrix of constants representing nearest neighbor interactions i.e. $\mathbf{B}$ consists of $+1$ on the upper diagonal and $-1$ on the lower diagonal.

I feel like techniques from quantum mechanics aught to work here, hence why I'm asking on PSE.

Edit:
The target space of this operator is the $n$-dimensional column vectors whose entries are functions of the variables $p\in[-\infty,\infty]$ and $t\in[0,\infty]$. If we denote the states $\psi$, then the following quantity is conserved in $t$,
$$\rho(t) = \sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\rm d}p\int_{-\infty}^\infty{\rm d}x e^{{\rm i} n x}\psi_n(t,p)\,.$$

Comment: What is $\phi$? If it is an angle, how does the third term make sense? Where does this operator come from?

Comment: $\phi$ represents the canonical momentum conjugate and it is not periodic. This operator comes from a Hamiltonian that is periodic in one of the canonical variables. The shape of $\mathbf{B}$ arrises by representing the solution as a Fourier series in the periodic variable.

Comment: Can you specify the space on which this operator is meant to act?  I'm a bit confused as to what all of these symbols mean.

Comment: To clear things up: vector space this operator works on is column vectors of length $n$ that are continuous functions of the variables $t$ and $\phi$.

Comment: Okay.  What is the inner product on this space?  I assume it's something like $\int_0^{2\pi} \psi^\dagger \psi \ d\phi$?

Comment: No, I suppose I picked a bad notation. The variable $\phi$ is a real number that does not represent an angle: it should be integrated from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I'm not sure what the appropriate inner product is here. Perhaps there is some generalization of Sturm-Liouville theory that would be useful to figure that out?

Comment: Okay, the point is though that  $t$ is not involved in the inner product.  Assuming your expression is of the form $ i\partial_t \psi = H\psi$, the operator to be diagonalized consists of the second two terms, but not $i\partial_t$.

Comment: The solution to this equation represents the fourier coefficients of a phase space density which is conserved in time, so I suspect you're correct. The object whose phase space volume does not change is $\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty \psi_n(t,\phi) e^{{\rm i} n\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the periodic variable conjugate to $\phi$, and the phase space measure is ${\rm d}\phi{\rm d}\theta$.

Comment: You might employ the variable $x\equiv t^{-3/2} \phi$ to simplify the operator.

Comment: Indeed - although that introduces an additional term coming from the change of variables, and it doesn't eliminate the explicit $t$ dependence. Also, to answer J. Murray's question about the inner product, it looks like the appropriate inner product is just as you said, except you extend the limits $\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\rm d}\phi\psi^\dagger\psi$

Comment: The object you wrote at the end of your edit doesn't have any $t$-dependence at all - it's just a number.  Did you mean to write that without the integral over $t$?

Comment: Oops thanks! Fixed.